# I can't change the value between two quotation marks with sed

Tags: sed, awk

How can I replace the word at the very end of the first line using sed?

```
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="j32h"'
test04
```

The result should look like below;

```
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="b254"'
test04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="j32h"'
test04
```

then

```
$ sed 's/"[^"]*"/"b254"/' file
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="b254"'
test04
```

Answer (score 1):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) we can use the double quote as a field separator, and replace he value of the 2nd field:

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\""} 
    NR == 1 {$2 = "b254"} 
    {print}
' <<END
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="j32h"'
test04
END
```

```
test00 ; test01 ; 'test02 -test03="b254"'
test04
```